# Pull posts by modified date instead of published date in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sql-order-by

So I'm using a theme which is using the published date mechanism for pulling the post and its content. The thing is I want to use the date factor and order the posts, but then because its using published date and not modified date, its not working for me. The current code

```
    if( !function_exists('wpestate_my_order') ):
    function wpestate_my_order($orderby) { 
    global $pdb; 
    global $table_prefix;
    $orderby = $table_prefix.'postmeta.meta_value DESC, 
    '.$table_prefix.'posts.ID DESC';
    return $orderby;
   }  

  endif; // end wpestate_my_order
```

Now is there anyway I can change the above code so it will pull by modified data?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please share your code where this function is being called wpestate_my_order('someVal')

Comment: Hello Mohsin, I've added below.. please check. Thanks for your time!

Comment: here's it: https://pastebin.com/gk3xzWrq